# Getting string with second occurrence using regexp_substr in oracle PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

Input value:

```
1-> 0055030_1-1-202201060155
2-> 0055040_1-8-202201050155-0501
```

Expected output for the corresponding input:

```
1-> 0055030_1-1
2-> 0055040_1-8
```

The below SQL queries do not return the expected output

```
select Regexp_substr('0055030_1-1-202201060155', '[^-^]+', 1, 1) from dual;
```

returns

```
0055030_1
```

```
select Regexp_substr('0055030_1-1-202201060155', '[^-^]+', 1, 2) from dual;
```

returns

```
1
```

Do I need to go substring or any pattern that will provide the required result?

Comment: Will there always be at least one '`-`' character, and if not, what would you want to see - the whole value, or null, or something else?

Comment: @AlexPoole, Yes always be at least two hyppen ('-') character in the input sting.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use regex and can instead use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`

```sql
WITH
    sample_data (test_str)
    AS
        (SELECT '0055030_1-1-202201060155' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '0055040_1-8-202201050155-0501' FROM DUAL)
SELECT test_str, substr(test_str, 1, instr(test_str,'-', 1, 2) - 1) as return_val
  FROM sample_data;


                        TEST_STR     RETURN_VAL
________________________________ ______________
0055030_1-1-202201060155         0055030_1-1
0055040_1-8-202201050155-0501    0055040_1-8
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the 'search for pattern version' of this function:
select Regexp_substr('0055030_1-1-202201060155', '(\d*)_(\d)-(\d)') from dual;

The pattern is: (\d*) multiple digits followed by
underscore, (\d) one digit, dash and one digit.
Should be replaced with '(\d*)_(\d*)-(\d*)' if the numbers between dashes have more than one digit.